# Bourbaki and the symbol for set inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, math-history

Which notation ($\subset$ or $\subseteq$) was preferred by Bourbaki for set inclusion (*not* proper)?

**A side question:** Was the notation for subset one of the many notations invented by Bourbaki?

Comment: And why exactly did someone vote to close this question?

Comment: Someone thinks this is primarily opinion based; which I do not agree, as I think the answer is "well-defined."

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'd say there is a definite, opinion-free answer to this. Whether it should have been on this SE or "History of Science and Mathematics" is another matter.

Comment: Someone possibly overread "Bourbaki" or didn't care. I've added the [tag:math-history] tag to convey the intention in the tags as well. I suggest clarifying or removing the second question, though. That one _is_ opinion-based.

Comment: I was thinking whether that was one of the many notations that Bourbaki might have introduced. However, I assume not.

Comment: @AlexR I wonder how opinionated the second question is, because "he" did have significant influence on $\emptyset$ as a symbol.  I don't think it's out of the question to ask if Bourbaki's possible use of $\subset$ (or $\subseteq$) was an important influence on today's standard usages.

Comment: @Hayden "Having a **significant** influence" is bound to be opinion-based since it contains an evaluating statement.

Comment: Anyway, I'm sure if Bourbaki actually invented this notation, this will be a part of the answer.

Comment: @AlexR I don't entirely agree, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Regret My bad. Still the scope of "this notation" is unknown from the question itself. It could ask if he somewhat "designed" the symbol used but just as well if he influenced further set notations.

Comment: @Gaussler That would be a good clarification (_Did he invent this notation?_) since this has a well-defined and neutral answer.

Comment: Oh my, another vote for closing this question. Did I do something to someone?

Comment: Would this question perhaps be more at home over at [hsm.se]?

Comment: Those votes to close make absolutely no sense. If someone thinks this is a bad question, they should simply downvote.

Comment: I think it might be the word "preferred" that makes people think this is opinion-based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See :

- Nicolas Bourbaki, [Théorie des ensembles](https://books.google.it/books?id=VDGifaOQogcC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed 1970) :

> *Définition 1* (**L'inclusion**). La relation désignée par $(\forall z)((z \in x) \implies (z \in y))$ dans laquelle ne figurent que les lettres $x$ et $y$, se note de l'une quelconque des manières suivantes : $x \subset y, y \supset x$, 
>   « $x$ est contenu dans $y$ », « $y$ contient $x$ », « $x$ est un sous-ensemble de $y$ ».

See English translation :

- Nicolas Bourbaki, [Elements of Mathematics : Theory of sets](https://books.google.it/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&pg=PA66) (1968), page 66.

---

Regarding [origins](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) :

> According to [Florian Cajori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florian_Cajori) (*A History of Mathematical Notations* (1928), vol. 2, page 294), the symbols  for "is included in" (*untergeordnet*) and  for "includes" (*übergeordnet*) were introduced  by [Ernst Schröder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Schr%C3%B6der) : *Vorlesungen über die Algebra der Logik*. vol. 1 (1890).

In addition, Schröder uses $=$ superposed to $\subset$ for *untergeordnet oder gleich*, i.e. $\subseteq$; see [Vorlesungen](https://books.google.it/books?ei=GRo-VdnvIqbT7Qar4IDIDw&hl=it&id=rIFKAAAAYAAJ&dq=Ernst+Schr%C3%B6der+Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Algebra+der+Logik&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=untergeordnet).

---

Giuseppe Peano, in [Arithmetices Principia Novo Methodo Exposita](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) (1889), page xi, uses an "inverted C" for *inclusion* :

> Signum $\text {"inverted C"}$ significat *continetur*. Ita $a \ \text {"inverted C"} \ b$ significat *classis* $a$ *continetur in classis* $b$ [i.e. : $\forall x(x \in a \to x \in b)$].

*Note*. It is worth noticing that in Peano there is the distinction between the relation : "to be an element of" ($\in$) and the relaion : "to be included into" ($\subset$).

This distinction is not present in Schröder.

---

According to Bernard Linsky, *Russell’s Notes on Frege’s* Grundgesetze Der Arithmetik *from §53*, in [Russell, 26 (2006)](http://russell.mcmaster.ca/j2602.htm), page 127–66 :

> Gregory Moore reports that Russell used $\supset$ for class inclusion as well as implication until March or April 1902, when he started to use $\subset$ for class inclusion.

Comment: And did Schröder write $\subset$ or $\subseteq$ for non-proper inclusion?